# Create Eraser Tool in python using OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pycharm

I am trying to write a program in pycharm in python using opencv. I am having problem in using mouse functions to erase an image.

I tried using mouse move functions to erase the image only when left button of mouse is clicked and when left button is released the eraser stops. But on output screen no action is done

```
import cv2
screen="Drawing"
img=cv2.imread("12.jpg")
cv2.namedWindow(screen)
```

eraser=False
     x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = 0, 0, 0, 0

```
 def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
      if (event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN):
            x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = x, y, x, y
            eraser=True
      elif (event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEHWHEEL):
            if eraser==True:
                  x_end, y_end = x, y

      elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            x_end, y_end = x, y
            eraser = False

   cv2.setMouseCallback(screen,draw_circle)
   while True:

    i = img.copy()
    if not eraser:
         cv2.imshow("image", img)

    elif eraser:
         cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 20, (255, 255, 255), -1)
         cv2.imshow(screen,img)

 if cv2.waitKey(1)==13:
     break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The program displays the image but i am not able to erase it by clicking the mouse buttons

Comment: `eraser` is not defined as a global in the function, so whatever you write to it, it will revert when the function returns (as any local variable)... just write `global eraser` at the beginning of the function

Comment: Sir, after declaring eraser as global variable the program is showing the image, but the eraser tool doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @api55 stated, `eraser` needs to be declared as a global variable. But so do the x and y coordinates of the circle you want to 'erase'. Your current code uses incorrect variables for that and also never updates them. That is why the eraser doesn't work.

By changing the code you can also do with less variables and without the while loop, making it more efficient. I took the liberty of refactoring your code and implement eraser size.

```
import cv2
screen="Drawing"
img=cv2.imread("12.jpg")
cv2.namedWindow(screen)
eraser=False 
radius = 20

def draw_circle(x,y):
        # 'erase' circle
        cv2.circle(img, ( x, y), radius, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        cv2.imshow(screen,img)

def handleMouseEvent(event,x,y,flags,param):
      global eraser , radius     
      if (event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE):
              # update eraser position
            if eraser==True:
                  draw_circle(x,y)
      elif (event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEWHEEL):
              # change eraser radius
            if flags > 0:
                radius +=   5
            else:
                    # prevent issues with < 0
                if radius > 10:
                    radius -=   5
      elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
              # stop erasing
            eraser = False
      elif (event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN):
              # start erasing
            eraser=True
            draw_circle(x,y)


cv2.setMouseCallback(screen,handleMouseEvent)
# show initial image
cv2.imshow(screen,img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```